# Access data from a local model

Tags: arrays, model, foreach, qooxdoo

Here is my problem, I hope some one can help me here, I'm developing a mobile app in qx.

In the `application.js` I call for a JSON in a server through the `qx.store.json(url)` that creates a model that I bind to a offline model to access the data offline in the app.

Everything good so far then when I try to access the data in the offline model it doesn't let me. The original JSON data is

```
array(timestamp=>time(),
      userdata=>array(
          array(userid=>0...),
          array(userid=>1...)))
```

When I debug the JSON or the offline data with `obj.getItem(1)` it always returns me `qx.data.model.userdata`.

I'm trying to use the data inside the array of `userdata` to validate a user in a `foreach` statement but `qx.data.model.userdata` always returns undefined.

I try `obj.getUserdata()`, `obj.getItem(1)`, `obj` being the offline model.

What am I doing wrong? It isn't a model a store for data, or it can only be used as binding data to an widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item at index 1 was an Array, `obj.getItem(1)` would return an instance of `qx.data.Array`. Since it returns an instance of `qx.data.model.userdata`, that means the model item is actually an object with a single property named "userdata" and you would access the value by calling `obj.getItem(1).getUserdata()`.

Comment: thanks i had to re format the json file so it would be more simple and now it works